# Catch exception second insertion of relation table (many to many)

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have an entity user and an entity role. They have a many to many relationship.

```
User user = new User(password.toString(), null, email, mobileNumber, 
                organisation, false);
userDAO.create(user);
```

When I insert an user, at the same time I add a role with it, so hibernate execute the next:

```
insert into user .....
insert into user_role_link ....
```

The problem is when I insert a null role with the user, the first statement is executed successfully and as I expect the second statement launch an error. Although it launches an exception, my code continue running, but I want to catch this exception in the second statement if something goes wrong. How can I do this? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The exception is `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'role_id' cannot be null`

If I catch the exception the email and the sms are sent. If a forced an error in the first insert the execution stops, but it doesn't happend in the second into statement.

```
public void registerUser(String email, String mobileNumber, Role role, String organisation) throws MessagingException {
        char[] password = RandomStringUtils.random(10, 0, 0, true, true, null, 
                new SecureRandom()).toCharArray();
        User user = new User(password.toString(), null, email, mobileNumber, 
                organisation, false);
        password = null;
        try {
            userDAO.create(user);

            String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            VerificationToken verificationToken = new VerificationToken(token, user);
            verificationTokenDAO.create(verificationToken);

            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("token", token);
            String bodyHTML = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "/com/port80/sftp/email/confirmregistration.vm", "UTF-8", model);
            String bodyTxt = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "/com/port80/sftp/email/confirmregistration_plain.vm", "UTF-8", model);
            emailSender.sendEmail(email, "subject", bodyTxt, bodyHTML);

            smsSender.sendSMS(mobileNumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("-------------------Catch Exception------------------------");
        }

    }
```

Comment: `"Although it launches an exception, my code continue running"` - That doesn't really make sense.  What is the exception?  How are you handling the exception?

Comment: If there is an exception, the stack unwinds. Nothing can carry on running. You must be catching the exception somewhere...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have edited my post and show my code. I am passing a null value in the User constructor to Role.

Comment: @David I have edited my post with more info. Thanks!

Comment: Your `catch` statement is a disciplinable offence at many companies. Catching without at least logging the stacktrace is something that you should never. ever. do.

Comment: @BoristheSpider This is just a simple and reduce version to show my code. Of course,  I log every exception in my app. Please, I am just concentrate in how to catch this exception I've mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @angeldev: The behavior being described doesn't make sense.  If an exception is thrown, the code does not continue to execute.  I suspect the debugging may be mistaken here.  Maybe the method is invoked a second time?  Maybe there's something happening on another thread?  Which line throws the exception being caught?  When you step through in the debugger, how does the code read the lines which send the messages?

Comment: @David When I debug this happend: everithing run well, the first insert statement is executed, the email is sent and the sms is sent. When all the method is executed is when the second insert statement is executed, so the exception is launched after the whole method run.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you just need to use a try-catch block (if I'm understanding you correctly). Like this:

```
 User user = new User(password.toString(), null, email, mobileNumber, 
            organisation, false);
 try
 {
      userDAO.create(user);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
       //Handle your exception here.
       //I recommend catching just your specific exception. Otherwise, you can grab exceptions and never know about them.
       //I would put it here for you, but you didn't specify what was being thrown.
 }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I edit my post with more infor.Thanks!

Comment: Based on your change, I would say that what you're trying to do (Pass null into the database) is impossible. You'll either need to edit your db schema to allow that column to accept nulls, or you need to pass a value in. Databases are particularly rigid in that regard. Edit: I recommend creating a blank role that all users are assigned to by default. It should have minimum (if any) permissions and should be a placeholder.

Comment: I am passing the null  on purpose, just to create the exception and try to deal with this situation. Just to deal with a situation when the user is saved and something goes wrong.

Comment: Why not just have a null check every time you attempt to save the user? It seems like you're just making more work for yourself by trying to solve a problem that realistically doesn't need to exist.

Comment: Yes, probably you are right and this situation could never happend. Just in case I will add a null check, it is a good idea. Thanks!